# Read md5 hash inside txt file and compare with a md5 hash of a file

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to detect virus of a file md5 hash. I had a list of virus md5 hash call viruslist, then I want to compare the md5 of eicar.com with the md5 hash inside the viruslist. It detected then it will print detected. But now output always show clear, is it I need to readlines or others??
Below is my coding for it.

```
import hashlib

md5_hash = hashlib.md5()

viruslist = open('C:/FYP/SecuCOM2022/viruslist.txt','rb')
virusinside = viruslist.readlines() 

a_file = 
open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/irustesting/eicar.com','rb')
content = a_file.read()
md5_hash.update(content)
digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
print(digest)
virus="detected"
novirus="clear"
if virusinside == digest:
    print(virus)
else:
    print(novirus)
```

Comment: `==` will never be true when you compare a list of items to a single item, just the same as `"a" = ["a", "b", "c"]` is not true, because a list of things is not the same as a single member of that list. If you want to do an efficient lookup for whether an item is part of a collection, consider using a set instead of a list for the purpose -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Now I understand, thanks for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `viruslist.txt` looks like

```
bc6e6f16b8a077ef5fbc8d59d0b931b9
2d9fd9fbccf64a485304d7596772f2b0
...
```

Then you will probably need to make the following changes.

1. Open `viruslist.txt` in text mode with `viruslist = open('C:/FYP/SecuCOM2022/viruslist.txt','rt')`. This is because the output of `hashlib.md5().hexdigest()` is a string not bytes.
2. Strip off the trailing newline of each line in `viruslist.txt`. For example `virusinside = [l.rstrip() for l in viruslist]`.
3. Use `in` instead of `==` and reverse the comparison of the digest. For example, `if digest in virusinside:`